# unix/linux can't unzip a file for elastic search

Tags: java, linux, macos, unix, elasticsearch

I am trying to install elastic search on my mac os 10.10.5

I am following this official page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_installing_elasticsearch.html

the page said

> curl -L -O http://download.elasticsearch.org/PATH/TO/VERSION.zip

I did this: `curl -L -O http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch-1-7-2.zip`

then the page said:

> unzip elasticsearch-$VERSION.zip

I did this (on the same directory)

```
unzip elasticsearch-1-7-2.zip
```

the result is:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of elasticsearch-1-7-2.zip or
        elasticsearch-1-7-2.zip.zip, and cannot find elasticsearch-1-7-2.zip.ZIP, period.
```

what am i doing wrong please? how to solve it

#### Update 1

I used this

```
jar xvf elasticsearch-1-7-2.zip
```

I didn't get any error message, but i don't see the extracted file. does that command extract the file to another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is wrong - what you are downloading and trying to extract is text of 404 page. Try this:

```
curl -O -L https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.2.zip
```